# use csv to copy and paste files from remote servers

Tags: powershell

I want a csv that has two columns, it will look like this. I need a script that'll copy a file from the old server and paste it in my local directory then from my local directory to the new server.

| Old_Server | New_Server |
| --- | --- |
| OServer1 | Nserver939 |
| Oserver2 | NServer32 |

Right now I only have a csv with one column and it has the old server names. The csv is in the temp so I have

`$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Servers.csv"`

*temp.csv*

| Old_Server |
| --- |
| OServer1 |
| Oserver2 |

I have the code that copies the file from the remote server to my local one.

```
forEach ($server in $servers){
copy -path "\\$server\D$\topsecret\secret.txt" -destination "C:\Temp\$server\TopSecret\"
}
```

I need to use the old servername to copy the file inside it from my local directory and paste it into the new server's location.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, using [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) (and [`Remove-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession)) in combination with [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)'s `-ToSession` parameter:

```bash
Import-Csv C:\Temp\Servers.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $toSession = New-PSSession $_.NewServer
    Copy-Item "\\$($_.OldServer)\D$\topsecret\secret.txt" `
              -Destination 'C:\some\local\path\on\the\new\server'
    $toSession | Remove-PSSession
  }
```

Of course, if you can target the target directory on the new server via a UNC path as well, you don't need to create an explicit session, and can use something like
`-Destination "\\$($_.NewServer)\D$\topsecret\secret.txt"`